# Wait and Sleep does not work on protractor

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, integration-testing

I'm having trouble testing a screen with automated tests, I'm filling in all input fields and then pushing the submit button, but wait / sleep doesn't seem to be working this causes the button to be pressed before the input is filled.

Why is my sleep / wait not working?

```
describe('Wizard - Organizacional data - Test Plan - 150454', function () {

const functionsPage = new functionObjectPage();

it('148454 - Incluir informações do administrador e Escritório.',  function() {

    browser.wait(until.presenceOf(element(by.id('openWizard'))), 30000, '');
    browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('#openWizard').click()");

    browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('#usuarioPrincipal').value = 'User master'");

    browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('#emailUsuarioPrincipal').value = 'master@master.com'");

    browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('#officeName').value = 'Office Name'");

    browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('#cnpj').value = '57375882000197'");

    browser.sleep(5500);
    browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('#btnNextStep').click()");

});

});
```

I don't know if browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; influences how sleep / wait works, or if any other config can influence it.
This is my protactor config:

```
var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
var env = process.env.env || 'local';
var config = require('./e2e/src/helper/config')[env];
var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');



exports.config = {
directConnect: true,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
},
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
framework: 'jasmine',
specs: [
  './e2e/src/*_spec.js',
],
suites: {
  pages: './e2e/src/*_spec_suite.js',
},
baseUrl: config.baseUrl,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
  showColors: true,
  defaultTimeoutInterval: 2000000,
  print: function () {}
},
onPrepare: function () {

  require('jasmine2-custom-message');

  var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');

  var junitReporter = new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
    consolidateAll: true,
    savePath: 'testresults',
    filePrefix: 'reportXMLoutput'
  });

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
    new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
      savePath: 'testresults/screenshots'
  }));

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(junitReporter);

  jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
      suite: {
          displayNumber: true
      },
      spec: {
          displayStacktrace: true,
          displayErrorMessages: true,
          displaySuccessful: true,
          displayFailed: true,
          displayPending: true,
          displayDuration: true
      }
  }));
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
  browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15000);
  browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
  }
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false` in your config which means you need to use `async/await` to perform step synchronously

```
describe('Wizard - Organizacional data - Test Plan - 150454', () => {

const functionsPage = new functionObjectPage();

it('148454 - Incluir informações do administrador e Escritório.',  async () => {

    await browser.wait(until.presenceOf(element(by.id('openWizard'))), 30000, '');
    await browser.executeScript("document.querySelector('#openWizard').click()");

etc..
etc..
```

Comment: If i use SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: true, wait and sleep works?

Comment: It works in both cases. If you don't want to use async/await and want to use PROMISE_MANAGER (which is obsolete) then just set it to true (without changing the syntax)